# Beagle Bone 128x64 Graphic LCD

Tags: python, graphics, beagleboneblack, lcd, beagleboard

I have a BeagleBoneBlack and im trying to find a way to control a 128x64 Graphic LCD using python(This display, more specifically http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-12864AZ-NSW-BBW-TR.pdf), and i dont know exactly how to do it.

Last time that i used this display i was working with a PIC16F877A using the MikroC compiler and it has a library specifically for this GLCD display so it was bearly easier. I searched superficially for some solution but i dont find anything, do you guys know some solution or i have to create my own library to this application?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to get something working quickly based on the [Linux Kernel FBTFT driver subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/drivers-staging-fbtft-README).

[Latest upstream sources](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/staging/fbtft) show a quite wide range of supported displays. At a cursory look the controller seems to be part of the KS0108 family:
`KS0107B / KS0108B; S6B0107B / S6B0108A; HD61203 / HD61202; AX6108 / AX6107; PT6608 / PT6607; SBN0064 / SBN6400; KS0708; S6B0708; ST7548; ST7588; NT7108; RA8808; RW1065; and equivalents.`

Please note that by default the [beagleboard.org Debian images come with an older kernel](https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Kernel_Options). At least it looks like the 4.14-ti kernel build config does enable FBTFT as a module. So if you're *really* lucky it might even work out of the box. Though I'd be prepared to rebuild the kernel.

Feel free to ask me to expand on certain aspects of the above. This is a high level view with some pointers right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if the pyLCD library can be used for solve my problem?